# Android won't show box-shadow with 0px blur?

Tags: iphone, css, android-browser

Is there an issue with Android's browser showing solid(no-blur) shadows?

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px #fff;
```

Renders link this in Android compared to Chome, iPhone or blackberry?

[image: box-shadow on Android]

You can fine the full CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/kEq3U/3/
My Android is 2.2.1 if you could have a [look on your Android](http://jsfiddle.net/kEq3U/3/show/) and let me know what you see?

Comment: Why don't you just use border?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug with the Android browser - it's very irritating. Your only option is to use blur radius of 1px or above.

Check out the bug report at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7531

One commenter there said they got around it by using 0.1f as a value - this didn't work for me when I last tried it - only 1px or above worked.

Comment: That's a shame. Sadly 0.1 doesn't seems to work. I think my fix for this will be to use a 1px blur for Android and live with it. If I didn't have the round corners I'd just use an 'outline'